# How Can we remove the HTML from string and return an object from it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string which looks like

```
var str = <strong>Result completed.</strong> This has been done by user steve at 2am
```

Now, from this string I would like to remove the `strong` as well as , I am trying divide this string in two parts,

```
{
  title: "Result completed.",
  desc: "This has been done by user steve at 2am"
}
```

So , is there any way I can get this result using javascript

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Is the format always the same? Always the same order? Always the same tags?

Comment: @Andreas Yes the format will be same everytime

Comment: Have you checkout the functions in JS's string object prototype? Like `.indexOf()` etc? Have you looked into Regex?

Comment: yes I checked but No luck, could you please help me with this ? @NicolasGoosen

Answer (score 1):

You can use split method in javascript

**example:**

```js
var str = '<strong>Result completed.</strong> This has been done by user steve at 2am';
var arrayStr = str.split('</strong>');
var objectResult={'title':arrayStr[0].replace('<strong>',''), 'desc':arrayStr[1]};
console.log(objectResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. Although, it is not the best practice I just wrote what came up in my mind first specific to your case. (the string you write). If there will be more HTML tags in your string the code below won't work properly. It is not perfect but it works fine.

```js
const str = '<strong>Result completed.</strong> This has been done by user steve at 2am';
        
const htmlRemover = (str) => {
  let title = "";
  let description = "";

  const arr = str.split('');

  const endOfOpeningTag = arr.indexOf('>') + 1;
  const startingOfClosingTag = str.search(/<\//);

  arr.slice(endOfOpeningTag, startingOfClosingTag).forEach((el) => title +=  el);

  const newArr = arr.slice(startingOfClosingTag, arr.length);
  const newEndOfOpeningTag = newArr.indexOf('>') + 1;

  newArr.slice(newEndOfOpeningTag, newArr.length).forEach((el) => description +=  el);

  return {title: title.trim(), description: description.trim()};
};

console.log(htmlRemover(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Parsing Libraries - JavaScript
https://scrapingant.com/blog/html-parsing-libraries-javascript

Comment: Please add this answer as a comment ! or explain by yourself